# Rewriting URL from htaccess is doing wrong

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a `Laravel` project and I have defined routes like:

```
Route::get('/', 'WebController@index');
Route::get('/user/signin', 'WebUserController@userLogin');
Route::get('/user/signup', 'WebUserController@userRegister');
Route::post('/user/save', 'WebUserController@userSave');
```

And the absolute routes of my project are:

`localhost/project/` (it's working ok)

`localhost/project/user/signin` wasn't working ok.

Then, I added a `.htaccess` file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

And the routes for `signin` and `signup` are working good, except when I'm trying to use `user/save` from `signin` is redirecting to:
`localhot/user/save`

What is wrong with my `.htaccess` fie?

Comment: Have you tried clearing your browser cache and using a 302 temporary redirect instead of your 301 permanent redirect? Redirect cache can puzzle the most experienced of developers.

Comment: Yes @Ultimater the cache is clear